# Accessing user's Google Plus profile with id_token

Tags: java, google-plus

I followed the Google's guide for Sign-in button at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth.
After successful sign-in in the browser, I get the id_token:

```
var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
```

and send it to the server, as instructed. There I'm able to verify it and get the payload:

```
GoogleIdToken idToken = tokenVerifier.verify(googleIdTokenString);

if (idToken != null) {
  return idToken.getPayload();
}
```

However, I have no clue how to get the user's profile from either the token or the payload.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/

Comment: I'd like to get the profile with use of Google+ API Client Library for Java.

Comment: Are you making a web application or Android? The link in your post is for web.